# ASP.NET CORE 2.2 Deployment Issue

Tags: iis, deployment, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm having the weirdest issue and I have no idea why.
When deploying our .net core 2.2 api to our local IIS server I get the following error message:

> HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure

After checking the event log I this is the error that I find:

```
Application: dotnet.exe
CoreCLR Version: 4.6.27207.3
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Digitise.Infrastructure.Services.DatabaseMigrator' has been registered.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Digitise.ApiBase.BaseProgram.Initialise(String[] args, IWebHost host) in C:\Projects\Digitise.AspNetCore\Digitise.ApiBase\BaseProgram.cs:line 17
   at Digitise.Api.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projects\Digitise.AspNetCore\Digitise.Api\Program.cs:line 27
```

It seems like the DI is not working correctly! The weird thing is if I run the `api.exe` or `dotnet api.dll` the API works perfectly :/

Anyone have any ideas? :)

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program    
    {
            public static object _lock = new object();
            public static bool _init = false;

            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args);
                Initialise(args, host);
            }

            public static IWebHost CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    //.UseIISIntegration()
                    .UseIIS()
                    .UseNLog()
                    .UseShutdownTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
                    .Build();

            public static void Initialise(string[] args, IWebHost host)
            {
                var logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "NLog.config")).GetCurrentClassLogger();
                try
                {
                    logger.Debug("App init");

                    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
                    {
                        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                        try
                        {
                            if (!_init)
                            {
                                lock (_lock)
                                {
                                    if (!_init)
                                    {
                                        lock (_lock)
                                        {
                                            services.GetRequiredService<DatabaseMigrator>().Migrate();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            logger.Error(ex, "An error occurred while starting up the app.");
                            throw;
                        }
                    }

                    host.Run();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    logger.Error(e, "Stopped app due to exception");
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

**DatabaseMigrator.cs**

```
public class DatabaseMigrator
    {
        private readonly TenantDbContext _tenantDbContext;
        private readonly IOptions<DatabaseConfiguration> _databaseConfig;
        private readonly ILogger<DatabaseMigrator> _logger;
        private readonly AdminTenantDbInitialiser _adminTenantDbInitialiser;

        public DatabaseMigrator(TenantDbContext tenantDbContext, IOptions<DatabaseConfiguration> databaseConfig, ILogger<DatabaseMigrator> logger, AdminTenantDbInitialiser adminTenantDbInitialiser)
        {
            _tenantDbContext = tenantDbContext;
            _databaseConfig = databaseConfig;
            _logger = logger;
            _adminTenantDbInitialiser = adminTenantDbInitialiser;
        }

        public void Migrate()
        {
           //migration logic
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sharing the program.cs code and DatabaseMigrator may help in catching the issue.

Comment: "Digitise.ApiBase.BaseProgram.Initialise(String[] args, IWebHost host) in C:\Projects\Digitise.AspNetCore\Digitise.ApiBase\BaseProgram.cs:line 17" .. Isn't the Initialize function defined and consumed in Program.cs ??

Comment: @PraveenRai I have a base class because we're using a microservices infrastructure so i just added it there

Answer (score 1):

I've just gone through a lot of pain fixing a similar problem. Pretty sure the problem is you using `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`, this does odd things when running with in-process hosting as in IIS. I replaced it with `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` and all worked fine.

Clue came from [Dotnet Core Multiple Startup Classes with In-Process Hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53783260/dotnet-core-multiple-startup-classes-with-in-process-hosting)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue started to show up after I updated some Nuget packages. Installing the latest .NET Core SDK has helped.