# HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure .NET Core

Tags: c#, iis-express, appsettings, asp.net-core-3.0

I am using .NET Core 3.0 and suddenly I am getting error below, yes it was working fine last week:-

Nonetheless something has changed and I can't workout what - seems to be related to a directory being wrong.
I have deleted the .vs hoping it would work after it is regenerated...

[image: Error]

I have followed below links but to no avail...

[HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53811569/http-error-500-30-ancm-in-process-start-failure)

[Reading and using appsettings.json in Program.cs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56954607/reading-and-using-appsettings-json-in-program-cs)

https://forums.asp.net/t/2159371.aspx?Application+LM+W3SVC+10+ROOT+failed+to+start+process+ErrorCode+0x80070005+

[Dotnet Core Multiple Startup Classes with In-Process Hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53783260/dotnet-core-multiple-startup-classes-with-in-process-hosting)

The Event Viewer shows:-

[image]

Adding StartUp.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("ADGroup", policy =>
                policy.Requirements.Add(new UserHelper.CheckAdGroupRequirement(Configuration["SecuritySettings:ADGroup"])));
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, UserHelper.CheckAdGroupHandler>();
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error/{0}");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });


    }
}
```

A nudge in the right direction would be highly appreciated....

Comment: show us your Startup.cs

Comment: @JeePakaJP StartUp.cs added

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html#background A report might rule out a few typical causes, but things like bitness mismatch are not yet implemented so you still have to manually check them.

Comment: @LexLi Am not using JexusManager

Comment: There's not enough here to help you. Some sort of exception is being thrown at startup, but that could be literally *anything*. You need to implement some sort of logging to see the actual exception, or simply run the application from the console via `dotnet MyApp.dll` on the server. You'll then be able to see any exceptions being thrown in the console window. If you can't solve it yourself at that point, edit your question to include the specific exception(s) being thrown.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - it works when I run it from the command line but I need it to work from IIS Express as I need to get the UserPrincipal (Person logged in)

Comment: One has nothing to do with the other. Running from the command line is just using Kestrel to serve the app instead of IIS Express. You can still login either way.

Comment: I agree I should be able to login either way but I am not - with IIS Express it was working last week.

Comment: Even I am getting a similar error, Web API was working in .Net Core 3.0 but started to get this error after upgrading to 3.1. The same application is still working well in other machine having Core 3.0. It has logged below two errors in event logger. 

Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\application_path\' failed to load clr and managed application. CLR worker thread exited prematurely

Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\application_path\' hit unexpected managed exception, exception code = '0xe0434352'. Please check the stderr logs for more information.

Answer (score 0):

just faced the exactly same issue yesterday. spent hours trying figure out it.

solution is the following:

some of your dependencies like nu-get package, another project, any .DLL is referenced a .Net version which runtime is not installed.

in my case my project is .net 3.1 and i was starting it using VS and IISExpress and one of the packages was referencing .net 6 but i had .net 3.1, 7.0, 8.0 only

it started working right after i installed .Net 6 runtime/hosting bundle

also pay attention that it may still work running just .exe and i think this is because of some .DLLs/packages are "lazy-loaded" and do not cause the issue on start but definitely will fail at exact code using them.

good luck!

*just to more people would be able to find this:*

Application /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT with physical root failed to load coreclr. Exception message: CLR worker thread exited prematurely

Application /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT with physical root hit unexpected managed exception, exception code = '0xe0434352'. Please check the stderr logs for more information.